# git clone of volley library does not create android manifest.xml file

Tags: android, git, android-volley

I did the clone of volley library by using git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley link but it does not create AndroidManifest.xml file and because of that android update project -p . command gives error as AndroidManifest.xml not found.Please give me the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the repository you [need to import it as a library project](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html):

> 1. Git clone the repository by typing the following at the command line:
>
>    ```
>    git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
>    ```
> 2. Import the downloaded source into your app project as an Android library project (as described in [Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html), if you're using Eclipse) or make a [.jar file](https://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary).

The instructions for **Setting up a Library Project** say that the `AndroidManifest.xml` file must be created manually:

> ### Creating the manifest file
>
> A library project's manifest file must declare all of the shared components that it includes, just as would a standard Android application. For more information, see the documentation for [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).
>
> For example, the [TicTacToeLib](https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/TicTacToeLib/AndroidManifest.html) example library project declares the activity `GameActivity`:
>
> ```
> <manifest>
>   ...
>   <application>
>     ...
>     <activity android:name="GameActivity" />
>     ...
>   </application>
> </manifest>
> ```

Comment: I tried to import the source but it shows error as 'select a directory to search for existing Android projects.

Comment: My volley source includes src folder,Android.mk,build.gradle,build,build,custom_rules,pom,proguard.cfg,proguard-project,rules.gradle.

Comment: @Shashikant, those instructions are for Eclipse. Are you using something else, like Android Studio?

Comment: @Shashikant, then I don't know what to say. Have you carefully followed [the instructions](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) under the heading "Setting up a Library Project"?

Comment: @Chris...Hey I did this...Thnk u so much...actually my clone source was not importing in eclipse...so I have downloaded the volley source from git and then imported in eclipse and now its imported successfully..

Comment: @Shashikant, I'm not sure how your two copies of the source code are different (both sound like `git clone` to me), but I'm glad you got this working.

Comment: ,Hey Chris can u do me a favor...could u suggest me any better android volley tutorial...so that i can refer it and I will implement it in my application..so that in future it will not make me any problem...because before volley I was using AsynTask and it every time crash my application..so I have turned to Volley...So I want to implement it correctly...

Comment: @Shashikant, I'm not familiar with that library and tutorial recommendations are [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your best bet is probably to ask on another site or to search around a bit.